# I need to load an input data in a modal window according to its condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

when validating and wanting to pass the data to the item to the input of the modal window it is duplicated in all and it should only be in the click

```html
<label for="">Valor de Comprobante</label>
<input type="text" class="valor_transaccionsinPunto" name="valor_transaccion" placeholder="valor de transaccion...">
<label for="">Valor Base sin IVA</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user valorBase" id="valorBase" name="valorBase" placeholder="Valor Base...">
```

```js
$('.calcular').click(function() {
  var valorBase = $('.valorBase').val();
  var valor_comprobante = $('.valor_transaccionsinPunto').val();
  var mecanismoRetencion = $(this).parent().parent().find(".mecanismo").text();
  if (mecanismoRetencion == 'Valor_Total') {
    //console.log('si');
    $('.baseFinal').val(valor_comprobante);
  } else {
    //console.log('no');
    $('.baseFinal').val(valorBase);
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try saving
`$(this).parent().parent().find(".mecanismo")` to a variable and logging it to the console, you will find out that you are getting ALL of the `.mecanismo` elements. I do not know the full structure of the HTML you're dealing with cuz you haven't shared a lot, but I think if you change `$(this).parent().parent().find(".mecanismo")` for `$(this).parent().find(".mecanismo")` you might solve this. Otherwise keep the original selector but wrap the entire row in another div so you limit the scope of the selector.

If you could add more details to the question I'd gladly edit this answer as I cannot yet post comments, cheers.